# Moving full Console information to TMemo

Tags: delphi, console, wifi, netsh

I'm using the following procedure to put the result of DOS commands in a `TMemo`:

```
procedure RunDosInMemo(DosApp: String; AMemo: TMemo);
const
  ReadBuffer = 2400;
var
  Security : TSecurityAttributes;
  ReadPipe, WritePipe : THandle;
  start : TStartUpInfo;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  Buffer : Pchar;
  BytesRead : DWord;
  Apprunning : DWord;
begin
  With Security do begin
    nlength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes) ;
    binherithandle := true;
    lpsecuritydescriptor := nil;
  end;
  if Createpipe (ReadPipe, WritePipe,@Security, 0) then begin
    Buffer := AllocMem(ReadBuffer + 1);
    FillChar(Start, Sizeof(Start), #0);
    start.cb := SizeOf(start) ;
    start.hStdOutput := WritePipe;
    start.hStdInput := ReadPipe;
    start.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES + STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    start.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
    if CreateProcess(nil,
      PChar(DosApp),
      @Security,
      @Security,
      true,
      NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
      nil,
      nil,
      start,
      ProcessInfo)
    then
begin
  repeat
        Apprunning := WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 200);
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      until (Apprunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
  repeat
        BytesRead := 0;
        ReadFile(ReadPipe, Buffer[0], ReadBuffer, BytesRead, nil);
        Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
        OemToAnsi(Buffer, Buffer);
        AMemo.Text := AMemo.text + String(Buffer);
      until (BytesRead < ReadBuffer);
    end;
    FreeMem(Buffer);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ReadPipe);
    CloseHandle(WritePipe);
  end;
end;
```

Then I use it with a copy of `netsh.exe` to get a list of wireless signals and MAC addresses like this:

```
RunDosInMemo('C:\Edge LR\netsh.exe wlan show networks mode=Bssid', Memo3);
```

But it shows only the first 9 wireless signals from the list. When I run it on the console directly, it shows the full list with all wireless signals and specs.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try `AMemo.Lines.Add( String(Buffer) ) ;` ?

Comment: Though @Remy is spot on in his answer below, I think it's worth considering not re-inventing the wheel. As I mention in my answer further down, you could just have solved the overall problem by using the Execute-function in the JCLSysUtils-unit written by the JEDI-team. It's very simple to use and solves *all* the technical ins and outs of the problem you face (using pipes and threads etc etc) - maybe it's not as much fun :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you read the following MSDN documentation, you will see that you are missing some very important steps:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

Most notably, you are using the parent process's read end of the pipe for the child process's STDIN, which is wrong.  And you are letting the child process inherit that read end of the pipe, which is also wrong.

You also need to close the write end of the pipe after the child process has inherited it, before you then start reading from the pipe.  Otherwise, the child process will not fully exit and signal the handle returned by `CreateProcess()`. By closing the write end, you ensure the process can fully terminate, and that `ReadFile()` will fail with an `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` error when the child process closes its end of the pipe and there is no more data to be read.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure RunDosInMemo(DosApp: String; AMemo: TMemo);
const
  ReadBuffer = 2400;
var
  Security : TSecurityAttributes;
  ReadPipe, WritePipe : THandle;
  start : TStartUpInfo;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  Buffer : array of AnsiChar;
  Str: AnsiString;
  BytesRead : DWord;
  AppRunning : DWord;
begin
  with Security do begin
    nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
    bInherithandle := true;
    lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  end;

  if not CreatePipe(ReadPipe, WritePipe, @Security, 0) then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    if not SetHandleInformation(ReadPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) then RaiseLastOSError;

    SetLength(Buffer, ReadBuffer);

    FillChar(Start, Sizeof(Start), 0);
    start.cb := SizeOf(start);
    start.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    start.hStdOutput := WritePipe;
    start.hStdError := WritePipe;
    start.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    start.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

    if not CreateProcess(nil,
        PChar(DosApp),
        @Security,
        @Security,
        true,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        nil,
        nil,
        start,
        ProcessInfo) then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      CloseHandle(WritePipe); 
      WritePipe := 0;

      repeat
        AppRunning := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, ProcessInfo.hProcess, False, 200, QS_ALLINPUT);
        if AppRunning = (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) then Application.ProcessMessages;
      until (AppRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);

      repeat
        BytesRead := 0;
        if not ReadFile(ReadPipe, Buffer[0], ReadBuffer, BytesRead, nil) then
        begin
          if GetLastError() <> ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE then RaiseLastOSError;
          Break;
        end;
        if BytesRead = 0 then Break;
        SetString(Str, @Buffer[0], BytesRead);
        AMemo.SelStart := AMemo.GetTextLen;
        AMemo.SelLength := 0;
        AMemo.SelText := String(Str);
      until False;
    finally
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(ReadPipe);
    if WritePipe <> 0 then CloseHandle(WritePipe);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
uses
  JCLSysUtils;

procedure TForm1.HandleOutput( const Text: string );
begin
  AMemo.Lines.Add( Text );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click( Sender: TObject );
begin
  AMemo.Clear;
  JCLSysUtils.Execute( 'C:\Edge LR\netsh.exe wlan show networks mode=Bssid',
                       HandleOutput );
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're going to suggest an entirely different approach, you really should demonstrate how to use it to solve the problem given in the question. Otherwise, you're just replacing one problem with another, which isn't helpful.

Comment: Very good, but I see that the UI is blocked during some operations. Do you mind providing some code or a reference to how that can be alleviated?